# Abrir contextmenustrip quando clicar com o botão direito nos itens exibidos na listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Tentei desta forma:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(listBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
        }
    }
```

Mas preciso que seja nos itens exibidos na listbox não na listbox inteira, como posso fazer?

Comment: Está a tentar evitar que o menu seja mostrado quando clica numa area que não tem items é isso?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo.

Comment: Porque não testa o `SelectedIndex` da `ListBox` ? Com esse consegue saber se tem algum selecionado e abre o menu em relação ao que está selecionado.